# Storing the alphabet through a queue

Tags: java

I'm trying to store the alphabet with a queue which length is 100, and to generate some errors with another small queue of value 4, if then the queue is full, as it should be in small queue, it prints "The queue is full" this is the code:

```
class Queue {
    char q[];
    int putloc, getloc;
    
    Queue(int size) {
        q = new char[size];
        putloc = getloc = 0;
    }
    
    void put(char ch) {
        if(putloc == q.length) {
            System.out.println(" - Queue is full.");
            return;
        }
        q[putloc++] = ch;
    }
    
    char get() {
    if(getloc == putloc) {
        System.out.println(" - Queue is empty.");
        return (char) 0;
        }
    return q[getloc++];
    }
}

class name {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Queue bigQ = new Queue(100);
        Queue smallQ = new Queue(4);
        char ch;
        int i;
        
        System.out.println("Using bigQ to store the alphabet.");
        for(i=0; i < 5; i++) {
            ch = 'A';
            System.out.println("Attemping to store " + (char) ('A' + i));
            
            smallQ.put((char) ('A' - i));
        
        System.out.print(ch);
        
    System.out.println("\n");
    
    System.out.println("Using smallQ to generate errors.");
    for(i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        ch = 'Z';
        System.out.println("Attemping to store " + (char) ('Z' - i));
        
        smallQ.put((char) ('Z' - i));
       
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
    
    System.out.print("Contents of smallQ: ");
    for(i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        ch = smallQ.get();
        
        if(ch != (char) 0) System.out.println(ch);
            }
      }
    }
}
```

The output of smallQ works, but the output of bigQ just prints the letter 'A' once, what can I do?

Comment: The alphabet is 26 letters long, or 52 if you have both lower and upper case letters. Why have a queue of 100?

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to use bigQ at all.

Comment: you have never used `bigQ` in your main inf first loop there's `smallQ.put((char) ('A' - i))` which should be `bigQ.out()` And the reason why it shows Just `A` is cause you  haven't close your first `for loop` of bigQ and it just taking one value that is A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had 2 bugs in this code which were:

1. For loop
2. You haven't used bigQ at all.

1.For loop: When we right `for loop` or `if` or `while` or `do while` if there's only one statement that is:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 5 ; i++)
    System.out.println("Running"+i);
System.out.println("Stop");
```

output:

```
Running0
Running1
Running2
Running3
Running4
Running5
Stop
```

the above code just executes the below line of `code` for `6` times and then print `Stop`
so if you didnt put brackets around loop it will just execute the line below it and go to the next line.

But when you write `for loop` with `brackets` it executes everything that's in the `{ }`
example:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i <= 5 ;i++) {
            System.out.println("Running"+i);
            System.out.println("Stop");
        }
```

Output:

```
Running0
Stop
Running1
Stop
Running2
Stop
Running3
Stop
Running4
Stop
Running5
Stop
```

Your for loop had the same issue you haven't closed the loop where it was necessary

2: You hadn't used bigQ at all in your code there was only samllQ in your `first` for loop and `second` for loop.

Fixed `class name` code below:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Queue bigQ = new Queue(100);
        Queue smallQ = new Queue(4);
        char ch;
        int i;
        
        System.out.println("Using bigQ to store the alphabet.");
        for(i=0; i < 5; i++) {
            ch = 'A';
            System.out.println("Attemping to store " + (char) ('A' + i));
            
            bigQ.put((char) ('A' - i));// <--changed
       
        } // <--changed
        
    System.out.println("\n");
    
    System.out.println("Using smallQ to generate errors.");
    for(i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        ch = 'Z';
        System.out.println("Attemping to store " + (char) ('Z' - i));
        
        smallQ.put((char) ('Z' - i));
       
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
    
    System.out.print("Contents of smallQ: ");
    for(i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        ch = smallQ.get();
        
        if(ch != (char) 0) System.out.println(ch);
            }
      
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Using bigQ to store the alphabet.
Attemping to store A
Attemping to store B
Attemping to store C
Attemping to store D
Attemping to store E


Using smallQ to generate errors.
Attemping to store Z

Attemping to store Y

Attemping to store X

Attemping to store W

Attemping to store V
 - Queue is full.


Contents of smallQ: Z
Y
X
W
 - Queue is empty.
```